# Tkz-berge does not respond to node-distance specification

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tkz-collection

I'm having some issues with the latest version of the `tkz-berge` package: it seems to be ignoring `node-distance` specifications. If I compile this file (using example n. 39 from the `tkz-berge` [documentation](http://altermundus.fr/pages/downloads/TKZdoc-berge.pdf)),

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} 


\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \SetVertexNoLabel
   \GraphInit[vstyle=Shade]
 \begin{scope}[rotate=-45]
    \grComplete[RA=6]{4}
 \end{scope}
{\tikzstyle{every node}=[node distance=1.64 cm]
 \NOEA(a2){a5}}
 \Edge(a2)(a5)
 \Edge(a1)(a5)
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \SetVertexNoLabel
   \GraphInit[vstyle=Shade]
 \begin{scope}[rotate=-45]
    \grComplete[RA=6]{4}
 \end{scope}
{\tikzstyle{every node}=[node distance=5.64 cm]
 \NOEA(a2){a5}}
 \Edge(a2)(a5)
 \Edge(a1)(a5)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get two identical graphs, in spite of the different `node distance` specifications:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Yes in the first version of `tkz-graph` and `tkz-berge` I used `node distance` but it's a problem because it's difficult to use scaling option. The link is towards an old version. You need to use the version ( V 1.00 c 02/06/2011) from TeXLive 2011 or from CTAN .

Now you have two possibilites, in the first example I used `unit=4cm` directly as an option of `\NOEA` and in the second I used
 `SetGraphUnit` (remark : in your case you don't need a TeX group but in a more complex example, a group is useful) . The macro and the option are defined by `tkz-graph`

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tkz-berge} %  V 1.00 c 02/06/2011 c for ctan
% the version from altermundus.fr is obsolete and I need to remove this version.

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \SetVertexNoLabel
   \GraphInit[vstyle=Shade]
 \begin{scope}[rotate=-45]
    \grComplete[RA=6]{4}
 \end{scope}

 \NOEA[unit=4cm](a2){a5}
 \Edge(a2)(a5)
 \Edge(a1)(a5)
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \SetVertexNoLabel
 \GraphInit[vstyle=Shade]
 \begin{scope}[rotate=-45]
    \grComplete[RA=6]{4}
 \end{scope}
{\SetGraphUnit{5.64 cm}
 \NOEA(a2){a5}}
 \Edge(a2)(a5)
 \Edge(a1)(a5)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @apc The documentation from my site is obsolete. It's preferable to use the `texlive` or the `ctan` version.